# PHP Cross Session Global Counter Variable (Shared Memory)

Tags: php

On a very busy PHP server, I am trying to get a global counter going and thought shared memory would be the way to go.  Ideally I would use APC

```
apc_add('counter',1);
apc_inc('counter',1);
var_dump(apc_fetch('counter'));
```

except that it is not available on the servers and I am restricted to what is available.  The servers do have shmop so tried to get that to work, however it seems to be session specific.  Is there anything else that could be used?

The shmop code I tried:

```
$shm_key = ftok(__FILE__, 't');
$shm_id = shmop_open($shm_key, "c", 0644, 8);

$shm_data = shmop_read($shm_id, 0, 8);

$shm_data = shmop_read($shm_id, 0, 8);
var_dump($shm_data);

if (empty($shm_data)) {
    //counter has not been set
    $shm_bytes_written = shmop_write($shm_id, 0, 1);
} else {
    $shm_bytes_written = shmop_write($shm_id, (int)$shm_data + 1, 0);
}

$shm_data = shmop_read($shm_id, 0, 8);
var_dump($shm_data);
```

Comment: Something like memcached/apc would be what I would suggest.  How about storing a value in a database (or even a flat file)?

Comment: @RocketHazmat it would be nice if I could use memcached/apc, but such is not the case.  Because the servers are very busy putting more strain on the DB is also not an option. I'll try the flat file...

Comment: if retrieving a value from a db is a "strain" something is wrong, as sites do this constantly